# escape sequence to parse the value inside double string in python

Tags: python, escaping, sequence

I have

```
a=2
b=4
```

I used

```
print 'cubit.cmd("create curve vertex %d %d ") %%(a,b)' %(a,b)
```

which gives

```
cubit.cmd("create curve vertex 2 4 ") %(a,b)
```

but I want to have only the part without % and afterwards. Like

```
cubit.cmd("create curve vertex 2 4 ")
```

I want to parse the commands to another software so I must use some variation of escape sequence.

Any suggestions?

regards

Comment: The string is hard-coded; just delete `%%(a,b)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your expected output is:

```
cubit.cmd("create curve vertex 2 4 ")
```

...just remove the part afterwards: it's just a string after all.

```
print 'cubit.cmd("create curve vertex %d %d ")' %(a,b)
```